# Where can I find ninject.web.mvc.dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I feel stupid for even asking this, but I can't find the file anywhere.

I've added Areas to my MVC 2 application. It caused some errors with Ninject, and after some research, I found the solution. Part of the solution is that I need new .dlls, ninject and ninject.web.mvc.

Everywhere I look, it says to go here (https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc) to get the .dlls. I've downloaded and searched through the download, and can't find it, it's not in there.

Where can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab the latest of everything from [our build server](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project3&tab=projectOverview) on codebetter.com. Just look at the build artifacts from whichever MVC version you are using.

Comment: Thanks. That's much easier than trying to build it myself, I kept running into problems.

Comment: this should be in the ninject wiki!! It took me like 4 hours to get it to compile (WebActivator did not have strong name, mvc did not have dependencies, even with NUGET, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You need to build them. There are instructions on how to build them in the download package.

Answer (score 0):

Once you download the source code from [GitHub](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc) you need to build it.