# Ninject Contextual Binding: Where do I get Ninject.Conditions.dll

Tags: ninject, ninject-2

I've read about ninjects contextual binding here : http://ninject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Contextual%20Binding

and am trying to get it working in my project. The docs state that I need to add a reference to Ninject.Conditions.Dll which I do not have. Does anybody know where to get this?

I've tried over at github : https://github.com/ninject/ninject
I used the download link to get the 2.0.1.0 sources and managed to build them but no dll.

I found a similar question here : [Where can I find ninject.web.mvc.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702426/where-can-i-find-ninject-web-mvc-dll)

and an answer with a link to a build server. I followed the link and I get a login request for team city.  I don't have an account.

Comment: Update: I found the Guest Login to team city as discussed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702426/where-can-i-find-ninject-web-mvc-dll/4702490#4702490  But there isnt any sign of Ninject.Conditions.  Any ideas anyone???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link is about a very old Ninject version. This is now in the main ninject assembly But the Syntax has changed.

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().When(request => DoSomeFilteringHere)
```

Or use one of the other When overrides.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't suppose you can point me at any docs / blog posts?

Comment: Good Idea! I looked but virtually no coverage in the build I have :-(.

Comment: in case anybody else is struggling with this look at the source for IBindingWhenSyntax - It has some usefull code comments!  http://code.google.com/p/ninject/source/browse/experiments/ninject2/src/Ninject/Syntax/BindingSyntax.cs?spec=svn151&r=146